# --default-unreachable-toleration-seconds and --default-not-ready-toleration-seconds are not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I updated kube-apiserver service with default toleration limits as 60 sec.

```
--default-unreachable-toleration-seconds=60 
--default-not-ready-toleration-seconds=60
```

I stopped kubelet in one of my node, it went to not-ready state.

But the problem I am facing is the pods are getting evicted only after 5 minutes from node moved to not-ready state. The expectation is pods should be evicted in 60 seconds.

My kubernetes version is 1.15.

I restarted the kube-controller-manager and kube-apiserver after I made this change.

What is wrong with the procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With those two default toleration parameters, Kubernetes will automatically add a toleration configuration to every pod. Therefore it is very important to redeploy all pods to ensure the toleration is added to all of your pods.

Alternative to changing parameters of kubernetes control plane components which makes it global change for all pod you can also modify the toleration time per pod using the following configuration.

```
tolerations:
  - key: "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable"
    operator: "Exists"
    effect: "NoExecute"
    tolerationSeconds: 60
  - key: "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready"
    operator: "Exists"
    effect: "NoExecute"
    tolerationSeconds: 60
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/#taint-based-evictions

Comment: I do not know that I had to redeploy my pods, will do that and check. Thanks for looking into it. I appreciate it. I will approve the answer after validating it.

Comment: I redeployed my pod and the tolerance value of the pods are not changed. 
```Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s```

Comment: you deleted the pod and re apply the yaml?

Comment: I have a replica-set, So I deleted the pod, so thee rs created a new pod again. should I completely wipe off the replicaset and create it from scratch? I am doing that, will update soon

Comment: ```NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
smsgateway-smsgw-bw-staging-fst-20200401-phase-k8s   1         1         1       105s
```
When I describe the pod I see the tolerance as 300s only.
The next option I am going to try is directly add this tolerance to pods instead of the cluster level.

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: With tolerations specified in the scope of pods, the pods are evicted on time after node becomes not-ready.